# Remove rows of differing type

Tags: python, filter, pandas

So I have a data frame, of which a column mostly consists of strings. However occasionally it contains a float. I need to filter the column so I only get strings. I tried converting the column via D-type to a string, but no luck. I was now attempting to filter via the following:

```
companies['variants'] = companies['variants'].filter(lambda x: isinstance(x,str))
```

But this produces an error:

```
    return self.reindex(**{axis_name: [r for r in items
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do this way:

```
companies['variants'] = filter(lambda x: isinstance(x,str), companies['variants'])
```

It should remove all elements which not str instance(of course if companies['variants'] contains list or tuple).

If you want to convert each element to string, you can do next:

```
companies['variants'] = map(lambda x: str(x), companies['variants'])
```

Comment: This will not work for Pandas dataframes as this assigns a function object to the companies dataframe column

Answer (score 1):

Generate a mask of the types that are strings:

```
mask = companies.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x.variants, np.str), axis =1 )
```

Now filter the non strings out:

```
companies = companies[mask]
```

Also you can do just this to convert all the data to a string:

```
companies['variants'] = companies['variants'].astype(np.str)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want a lambda, why not just coerce the value?

```
companies['variants'] = str(companies['variants'])
```

Comment: It returns list, converted to string. As I understand we need to get filtered list object, that contains only strings